# Passing parameters to WebMethod as JSON objects

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I'm getting various errors when I pass parameters to my `WebmMethod`.  Below are my various tries and the errors I get:

`globalData` is an array, `mapping` is an array that can be deserialized to `List<Mapping>`, `selectedFund` is an integer.

**C# WebMethod**

```
[WebMethod]
public static void ProcessData(string data, List<Mapping> mapping, int selectedFund)
{
    //blah blah
}
```

**Try 1**

```
var payload = new Object();
payload.data = globalData;
payload.mapping = chosenMappings;
payload.selectedFund = $selectedFund.val();

$.ajax({
//...etc
data: JSON.stringify(payload),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
}
```

**Error:** `System.String` is not supported for serialization of an array.

**Try 2**

```
$.ajax({
//... etc...
    data: {
        data: JSON.stringify(globalData),
        mapping: JSON.stringify(chosenMappings),
        selectedFund: $selectedFund.val()
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

**Error:** Invalid Json primitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... I needed to do `JSON.stringify()` twice.  Once outside, then once inside...

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
type: 'POST',
dataType: "json",
//data: JSON.stringify(payload),
data: JSON.stringify({
    data: JSON.stringify(globalData),
    mapping: JSON.stringify(chosenMappings),
    selectedFund: $selectedFund.val()
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the content type in the jQuery JSON post:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

check this article

```
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/
```

Comment: Sorry, I do have that included in contentType.